# How to send an error message with 200 status code using Model Binding in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, model-binding

I've made a project in which if a certain property is sent empty or null, it should return an error message when that API is hit. I am using model binding to achieve this, I've added the following code into the "Startup.cs" class:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o =>
{
    o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
    new BadRequestObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState);
});
```

It sends the error message, but with 400 Bad Request status code, where I want it to be 200 Success.

I've already tried to use "OkObjectResult" replacing the "BadRequestObjectResult", but the problem is that it then also shows other generated error content along with the error message in the response with 200 status code, which is something I don't want. I want the actual error message in the response body only (no metadata).

```
{
"Name": {
    "rawValue": null,
    "attemptedValue": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "exception": null,
            "errorMessage": "Name is required" \\Only want this message
        }
    ],
    "validationState": 1,
    "isContainerNode": false,
    "children": null
}
```

Comment: trying to counteract the HTTP status codes by sending a "success" code with a message telling the user why their request ***was not*** a "success" is a really bad idea, and can be just plain confusing to your users.

Comment: Could you give some details about how you are consuming this API? What is showing the "other generated error content"?

Comment: Then remove from the body of the response what you do not want.

Comment: Why don't you just send back custom "error" message in AsyncResult?

Comment: @JackA. Updated, please review.